# OpenApi send MultipartFile request with JSON get 'application / octet-stream' error not supported

Tags: spring-boot, maven, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm using Spring Boot and I want send MultipartFile with json using Swagger UI but I receive the error `'application/octet-stream' error not supported`,if I use Postman work very well.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST,
produces = { "application/json" },
consumes = { "multipart/form-data" })
public String hello(
   @RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file,
   @RequestPart("grupo") Grupo grupo) {
      if (file != null) {
        logger.info("File name:  " + file.getOriginalFilename());
      }
      logger.info(grupo.toString());
   return grupo.toString();
 }
```

How to  resolve this?

- springdoc-openapi-ui 1.4.4
- Spring Boot 2.3.2.RELEASE
- spring-boot-starter-web
- Maven
- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send a json with multipartFile, use the annotation `@Parameter` with type `"string"` and format `"binary"`, so that you can send a file with format json.

```
@Parameter(schema =@Schema(type = "string", format = "binary"))
```

And then it will be like this.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/test", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE )
public ResponseEntity<Void> saveDocu2ment(
        @RequestPart(value = "personDTO") @Parameter(schema =@Schema(type = "string", format = "binary")) final PersonDTO personDTO,
        @RequestPart(value = "file")  final MultipartFile file) {
    return null;
}
```

Reference - [Multipart Request with JSON - GitHub Springdoc openApi](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/820#issuecomment-672875450)

Comment: How can this be an accepted answer, why would i send a json as a file !!

Comment: @rpajaziti No, JSON you send your data who is **"personDTO"*** like: name, age, email, etc, and the **"file"** you send your file, so this is mixed json with file sharing on an endpoint

Comment: it's not an actual answer but maybe workaround, it's accepting json as well as a binary file: check this https://prnt.sc/X90pOyBMBaJ9

Comment: This is right solution actually, https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/6462#issuecomment-1069115246

Answer (score 3):

Following the link provided by @Vishal Zanzrukia

I added this configuration:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.boot.info.BuildProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;



@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfig {

    /**
     * 
     * This method is needed to allow sending multipart requests. For example, when an item is 
     * created together with an image. If this is not set the request will return an exception with:
     * 
     * Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 
     * 'application/octet-stream' is not supported]
     * 
     * @param converter
     */
    public OpenApiConfig(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter) {
        var supportedMediaTypes = new ArrayList<>(converter.getSupportedMediaTypes());
        supportedMediaTypes.add(new MediaType("application", "octet-stream"));
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(supportedMediaTypes);
    }
...
```

And now it seems to be working as expected with a code like this:
`Controller.java`

```java
    @PostMapping(path = "/", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Item> createItemWithoutImage(@Valid @RequestBody Item item) {
        Item createdItem = itemService.createItem(item);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(createdItem);
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Item> createItem(@Valid @RequestPart Item item,
            @RequestPart(name = "image", required = false) MultipartFile imageFile) {

        // DO Something with the image

        Item createdItem = itemService.createItem(item);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(createdItem);
    }
```

This is how it looks in swagger:
[image: endpoint_in-swagger]