# OpenApi send MultipartFile request with JSON

Tags: spring-boot, multipartform-data, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

Is there a better solution than this ([OpenApi send MultipartFile request with JSON get 'application / octet-stream' error not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63367971/openapi-send-multipartfile-request-with-json-get-application-octet-stream-er)) yet?

```
@PostMapping(path = "", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
@Operation(summary = "XX", requestBody = @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(description = "Das zu erstellende Ticket", content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = TicketDTO.class))))
TicketDTO createTicket(@RequestPart() @Parameter(required = true) TicketDTO ticket,
        @Parameter(description = "Files to be uploaded", content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)) @RequestPart(value = "files", required = false) MultipartFile[] files)
        throws MessagingException;
```

This is not working for me. I do not see the option to upload files in the Swagger UI.

Comment: Do you use Springdoc or Springfox? The [solution](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/820#issuecomment-672875450) that the linked answer references is for Springdoc.

Comment: I use Springdoc.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set requestBody in @Operation.

example

```java
  @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
  @Operation(summary = "XX")
  public TicketDTO createTicket(@RequestPart() @Parameter(required = true) TicketDTO ticket,
                         @Parameter(description = "Files to be uploaded", content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)) @RequestPart(value = "files", required = false) MultipartFile[] files) {
    return ticket;
  }
```