# springdoc-openapi sends the requests as application/octet-stream instead of multipart/form-data

Tags: spring-boot, springdoc

Stuck at this, facing the same problem but unable to find any satisfactory and working answer. Anyone from the community please help me resolve the issue.

My versions are different :

```
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>

                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

please find the problem here :

[OpenApi send MultipartFile request with JSON get 'application / octet-stream' error not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63367971/20292999)

Read many solutions on stackoverflow, only to find that none of them helps.

Answer (score 0):

I added a response in the same link you provided. Basically I added:

```java
@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfig {

    /**
     * 
     * This method is needed to allow sending multipart requests. For example, when an item is 
     * created together with an image. If this is not set the request will return an exception with:
     * 
     * Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 
     * 'application/octet-stream' is not supported]
     * 
     * @param converter
     */
    public OpenApiConfig(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter) {
        var supportedMediaTypes = new ArrayList<>(converter.getSupportedMediaTypes());
        supportedMediaTypes.add(new MediaType("application", "octet-stream"));
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(supportedMediaTypes);
    }
```

And now model and file are sent correctly through swagger.